# How to fine-tune Plotly's dragmode = 'select' with barcharts

Tags: r, plotly

I am wondering if it is possible, to fine-tune Plotly's `dragmode = 'select'`?

More specifically, can I change when a bar is selected? Currently more than 50% of a bar must be selected in order for it to appear selected. Can I change that?

**I would like to select a bar already if 10% percentage of it is dragged.**

The following example + image should illustrate my problem easier than with words :)

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data = iris[1:5,]) %>% 
  add_bars(x = 1:5, y = ~Sepal.Length) %>% 
  layout(dragmode = "select")
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is related to the selected area of the bar. The selection is triggered when the datapoint which is represented by the bar (X/Y coordinates - 2/4.9 in your example) is included in the selection.

Comment: I think so too, but I was using the area to illustrate my problem or my customers problem :)

Comment: Click- or hover-selection is not an option?

Comment: No I am fine with those, it is specifically for the drag-selection.